# TFS 2017 - Bug in summary tab of release management

Tags: tfs

there appears to be a bug in the summary tab of the release management UI.  The "Completed" time does not accurately reflect when the deployment status of a task is set to failed.  The completed time in this instance is set to 8 hours ago, yet when the status of a task is set to succeeded, the completed time is set accurately. In the attached screen print the SQA - Manual Test was set to succeeded and the completed time of 18 minutes ago is accurate.

Does anyone know if this is truly a bug, or if I am misinterpreting what I am seeing?

[image]

Comment: How did you set the status? For the `SQA - Manual Test was set to succeeded`, is the test running for about 6 days? Whatever you can hover the mouse on the Complete time (`8 hours ago` here), the real complete time will pop up, then you can check if the time reflect the action.

Comment: Hi Andy, I am not sure the sequence of events of how the status got set.  It was through the Build & Release Management User Interface.  I still would like to know why the correct completion time showed up in the UI for the succeeded task of SQA Manual Test, but not the two items that were set to failed at the same time the SQA Manual Test was set to succeeded?  We need to have this accurately reflected in the UI without hovering your mouse over the Completed time.  This looks like a bug or design flaw to me.

Comment: Does other projects/releases have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, both the succeeded and failed completed time are OK on myside. But the string "`xx months/days/hours/minutes ago`"  in the UI is by designed. You can get the real time by hovering the mouse there.

Whatever, I have submitted an [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32849857-see-the-accurate-deploy-completed-time-without-hov) to suggest the feature you mentioned :  "`We need to have this accurately reflected in the UI without hovering your mouse over the Completed time.`" You can go and vote it to achieve that in future.

Comment: @Tim Stevens Is that answered your question? any update?